# What is the sum of the lengths of the radii of the circles in centimeter?

Tags: geometry

Two circles have their centers on the same diagonal of a square. They touch each other and the sides of the squares as shown. The square has a side of length $1$ cm.

[image]

Since the length of the side of the square is $1$ cm, I can find the total length of the circles using triangular properties, which would be $\sqrt{2}$. However, I am not able to continue and find the sum of the length of the radii of the circle.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

write an expression using this diagram involving $R$ and $r$ and $1$ and then simplify it

[image]

Comment: i still don't understand. I can make one equation. sqrt(2) = 2R+2r+what remains at the edges. But how to proceed further

Comment: If you take the four parts of the whole diagonal you have the diagonals of the two smaller squares plus two radii so get $\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2} R + R + r +\sqrt{2} r$ which is easily simplified

Answer (score -1):

The information of this problem is insufficient to find the sum of the lengths of the radii of the circles, which is evident from the illustration you provided. From it one can see, that the two circles can be of uneven sizes to satisfy the condition that the centres of the two circles must be on the diagonal. But one could also put the centres of two circles with the same radius on the diagonal, which would have different radii.

The only information we are given is that the sidelength of the square is 1cm, which doesn't say anything about the radii of the circles.

Comment: Sure we cannot find individual radii, but their sum is a constant and is determinable just from the side of square, as hinted in other answer. So the information in question is sufficient for what is being asked.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the answer